# Changing value in (key,value) of object in ng-repeat does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an JSON object which I show in the html using ng-repeat. But when I make changes to the value in the html and try to print it again, it does not get reflected in the actual object.

This is my html snippet :

```
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in object">
                <td>{{key}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value">{{value}}</input></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <a href="">
             <button ng-click="printer()" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </a>
```

This is my controller:

```
MyService.getObject(objectName).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.object = response;
    });

    $scope.printer = function() {
        console.log("inside printer function");
        console.log("object is ===" + JSON.stringify($scope.object));
    }
```

Here MyService has an http get which returns a JSON object which I assign to`$scope.object`. I can view the object without any problems but when I change it and print it, I am not able to see the changes I made.
There is a `Submit` button in my html which calls the `printer` function. After changing the value in my page, and clicking on submit, I am not able to see the changes.

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="value">{{value}}</input></td>
```

^^ here I have printed the value next to the text field. Any change I make to the text field also changes the value which means it works. But it does not get updated in the `$scope`

Comment: can you create jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: I have posted the part which needs help. Anyway I will get a fiddle done now.

Comment: @evc oops yup its a duplicate. Atleast can you remove the downvote ?

Comment: @ViChU no, you must check previous questions before asking, here's guideline for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, but this time, ok, I'll remove downvote, just edit something in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="value">{{value}}</input></td>
```

should be:

```
 <td><input type="text" ng-model="object[key]">{{value}}</input></td>
```

model value doesn't exist in your controller.